# Unwanted Uneven Stripped Table Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Titatoggle -->
    <link href="titatoggle-dist.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:70%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Fields</th>
                <th>Information</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <!-- Customer Info -->
                <td width="40%">Name</td>
                <td width="60%"> <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" style="display:table-cell; width:100%" placeholder="Enter full name"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <!-- NRO POC -->
                <td width="40%">Address</td>
                <td width="60%"> <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" style="display:table-cell; width:100%" placeholder="Enter address"></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <!-- Customer organization -->
                <td width="40%">Company</td>
                <td width="60%">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="organization" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                            Customer Organiztion
                                          </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm not sure what is causing my first two rows of my bootstrap table(table-striped) to appear dark

[Faulty Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqZyl.png)

I couldn't figure out how to add my CSS files but I used the bootstrap template with this link: https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/. I had to remove the rest of the table to ensure data security but it didn't have this problem other than the first two rows of the table. Also, initially I didn't even have a table header row and the problem was still there. Thanks to anyone who can help its greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap table is using the first row as table head, hence it is bold. You can overwrite the this in CSS file by adding a different class to the element.

```
tr:first-child td {
    background-color: #your_color;
}
```

or

```
tr:nth-child td {
    background-color: #your_color;
}
```

Or maybe you are using `.table-striped` class to your table.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the solution if your problem is solved so that it will help others.